# How to select data with set condition $_POST is empty and has value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I want to select data from my database using PHP and ajax call function.
In the select function, I use $_POST from a `textbox`. I have made a PHP and ajax call function on my page but something is wrong. I use `isset[]` for checking the `$_POST` data that I get from my `textbox`. I use an `if` condition in there - when the `$_POST` is empty it selects all data without a where clause, and when a specific `$_POST` has a value, it will select data *with* a where clause.

The problem here is that when I use data in my `textbox` for rendering a string to my PHP `$_POST`, the else condition on my PHP doesn't run.

This is my code that I use:

**JavaScript/jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var data = $("#report_all").serialize();  

    $('#all_report thead').empty();
    $('#all_report tbody').empty();
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "Post",
        url: "../php/report/report_all_wjm.php",
        success: function(data){
            var list = JSON.parse(data);
            var th = "";

            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'No'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Storage Location'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Kode Material'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Nama Material'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'No.Polisi'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Id Identifier'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Date'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Netto'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Uses'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Unit'+"</center>"+"</th>";
            th += "<th>"+"<center>"+'Payroll'+"</center>"+"</th>";

            th += "</th>";

            $("#all_report thead").append(th);
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

                var tr = "<tr>";

                tr += "<td>" +(i+1)+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['sloc']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['kode']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['nama']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no_pol']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['id']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['date']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['netto']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['uses']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['unit']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['payroll']+"</td>";

                tr += "</tr>";

                $("#all_report tbody").append(tr);
                $("#all_report").show();
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

**PHP**:

```php
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$date_awal=$_POST['date_start'];
$date_akhir=$_POST['date_end'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
$kode1=$_POST['kode_mat1'];
$sloc=$_POST['s_loc'];
$sloc1=$_POST['s_loc1'];
$type=$_POST['get_type'];
//Display all data
if (isset($date_awal) == "" || isset($date_akhir) == "" || isset($sloc)== "" || isset($sloc1)== "" || isset($kode)== "" || isset($kode1)== "" || isset($type)== "" ){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm ORDER by no asc";
    $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $rows = array();

    while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $rows[] = $tmp;
    }
}
//Display all data by one date
else  {
    // Data for Titik1
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' order by kode asc ";
    $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $rows = array();

    while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $rows[] = $tmp;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @AlexHowansky hmmm.. let me ask something. is any syntax similiar with this `$stmt->execute` i dont know how to use `->` this syntax. and i have try using a syntax with `->` and i get error in there

Comment: I find it truly odd that beginners get hung up on PHP objects or PHP OOP, but they're happy to use it all day long in javascript...

Comment: `->` is the object reference operator. Google "php oop" for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add where clause only when there is some value in variable $date_awal (ie $_POST['date_start'] ) then I would say to check it in if condition & other part should go in else part..
Also you can keep the mysqli_query & while loop outside the ifelse condition as those parts are same in both cases.

```
$rows = array();

if( date_awal != '' ){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' order by kode asc ";
}else{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm ORDER by no asc";
}

$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: nice this is that i want.
thx AJM
btw can you explain it to me?
`date_awal != ' '` meaning has a value of `$date_awal` right?

Comment: i have try something like Anil said in the answer but i'm still getting the value of all select

Comment: i want to know `date_awal != ' '` function.
because i want embed one condition again in there.
with `else if ( date_awal != '' && kode !='')` i try it but i can't catch the function in this `else if`

Comment: date_awal is not a function it's your variable name.. I looks the $ got removed.. It should be like:
if( $date_awal != '' )

And if you want to add more condition then your condition should work if you add "$" sign before your variables in the line ( date_awal != '' && kode !='')

Answer (score 0):

you cannot check isset in variable. instead do like this

```
if ($date_awal == "" || $date_akhir == "" || $sloc == "" || $sloc1 == "" ||  $kode == "" || $kode1 == "" || $type == "" ){

}else{

}
```

Comment: i have try your code. and the code in my else function not working.

Comment: then your one of the variable is empty

Comment: i think you want to do && instead of ||

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` returns a boolean, but you're comparing it to a string, so this doesn't make much sense:

```
if (isset($date_awal) == "") { ... }
```

It should be used like this:

```
if (isset($date_awal)) { ... }
```

However, you probably want to use `empty()` instead of `isset()`. If a variable exists and contains an empty string, `isset()` will still return true, which probably isn't what you want. You probably want this:

```
if (!empty($date_awal) || !empty(...) || !empty(...) ... ) {
}
```

Note:

```
$foo = '';
var_dump(isset($foo));
var_dump(empty($foo));
```

Outputs:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```